# Extending MenuItem in Android Java

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm a newbie Android Developer and my goal is to extend **MenuItem** in my custom **AppCategory** class.
I've understood that I need to implement it rather than extend it because **MenuItem** in an interface, but unfortunately it forces me to implement all it methods by myself. My question in how to find out most elegant solution?

```
public class AppCategory extends MenuItem {
    private String name;
    private String displayName;
    private String iconFile;
    private MenuItem navItem;

    private List<App> appsList;

    public AppCategory(String name, String displayName, String iconFile, List<App> appsList, Menu menu) {
        this.name = name;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.iconFile = iconFile;
        this.appsList = appsList;

        this.navItem = menu.add(this.displayName);
        int iconResNum = getResId(this.iconFile, R.drawable.class);
        navItem.setCheckable(true);

        // Icon image was found
        if (iconResNum != -1) {
            navItem.setIcon(iconResNum);
        }

        this.navItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getDisplayName() { return this.displayName; }
    public String getIconFile() { return this.iconFile; }
    public List<App> getAppsList() { return this.appsList; }
}
```